# What is the equivalent value for NSRange.location on the Range Object within Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, range, nsrange

Did someone can give me a hint which property of a Range is the equivalent property to the location property of an NSRange.

Especially I'm interested how I would migrate the following line of code from Swift 2.3 -> Swift 3.0

```
if myRange.location != NSNotFound { ... }
```

myRange is still a Range property and so the compiler tells me correct:
*Value of Type Range has no member location*

Is it enough to check the empty property?

```
if !myRange.isEmpty { ... }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most functions that used to return a range with `NSNotFound` now return an optional Range instead. So it should be enough to check that the range is not `nil`.

Comment: Good to know! In my case it is a self created range over a Data-Object (previously NSData), therefore the nil check doesn't work.

Comment: If it's a function you've written yourself then change it to return an optional ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the comments say, instead of returning NSNotFound you will get a nil range.

To answer your question though .location has been replaced with .lowerBound and .upperBound.

```
let s = "The yellow dog is nice"
if let range = s.range(of: "dog")
{
    print(s[range.lowerBound...]) //prints "dog is nice"
    print(s[range.upperBound...]) //prints " is nice"
    print(s[range.lowerBound..<range.upperBound]) //prints "dog"
}
```